# ) expected or missing

Tags: android

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = HomeActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ImageButton imageButton;
    private ImageButton imageButton2;
    public ImageButton imageButton4;
    public ImageButton imageButton5;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private ImageView imageView2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        imageButton2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        imageButton4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
        imageButton5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);


    //Single player button click event
       imageButton4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                 finish();
                };},


       //multi player game button event
    imageButton5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                MultiPlayer.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
            };}),

    //Settings button event
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  {
        @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                MusicActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
            }
        });


}}
```

there is a problem in this code as in this ')' is missing somewhere. Cursor shows the missing component in setting button event. It is not build because of this error.There is missing of ')' which terminates the compiler and failed to build.

Comment: Aren(t you using an IDE that tells you on what line the character is missing?

Comment: The error is really obvious. I would recommend you to go through some tutorials on Java before working on Android.

Answer (score 2):

you are never closing your first onclicklistener at imagebutton4

```
imageButton4.setOnClickListener**(**new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                 finish();
                };},
```

the end row should be like this

```
 }}),
```

but i am not really  getting the sense of These kommas behind there

Answer (score 0):

Error in your onClickListener :

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {
 private static final String TAG = HomeActivity.class.getSimpleName();
 private ImageButton imageButton;
 private ImageButton imageButton2;
 public ImageButton imageButton4;
 public ImageButton imageButton5;
 private ImageView imageView;
 private ImageView imageView2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    imageButton2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    imageButton4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
    imageButton5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);


    //Single player button click event
    imageButton4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                                    MainActivity.class);
                                            startActivity(i);
                                            finish();
                                        }});


            //multi player game button event
            imageButton5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            MultiPlayer.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }});

            //Settings button event
            imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            MusicActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            });


}}
```

Comment: You need to close the onclicklistener for imageButton4